# TCP Message sending gone wrong (missing about 1700 characters after sending a 5700 character message)

Tags: java

In my TCPClient class, when I send a message, I end up missing the last ~1700 characters. I have narrowed it down to the fact that I mess up in my math. I somehow tell it that it is the last message too soon.

So in short. I end up missing only the last ~1700 characters.

(`writeEOF()` tells the server that it is the end of the current package)

### My code:

```
public final void writeString(String out) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = out.getBytes();
    int numOfMessages = bytes.length / (BUFFER_SIZE - 1);

    if (bytes.length > BUFFER_SIZE - 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfMessages; i++) {
            writeHeader(new RequestHeader(clientId, getNextRequestId(),
                    RequestCommand.SEND_DATA, false, // false tells it that it is not the last message.
                    (byte)(i + 1)));
            output.write(bytes, i * (BUFFER_SIZE - 1),
                    (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
            ));
            writeEOF(); // tells the server to return the current buffer, and expect a new message. While it is not the last message, it just appends the buffered message to a StringBuilder
            RequestHeader header = handleHeader();
            if (header == null || header.getRequestCommand() != RequestCommand.ACK) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to send message: " + lastRequestId);
            }
        }
        writeHeader(new RequestHeader(clientId, getNextRequestId(), RequestCommand.SEND_DATA, true, (byte) (numOfMessages)));
        output.write(bytes, numOfMessages * (BUFFER_SIZE - 1), bytes.length - (numOfMessages * (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)));
        writeEOF();
        RequestHeader header = handleHeader();
        if (header == null || header.getRequestCommand() != RequestCommand.ACK) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to send message: " + lastRequestId);
        }
    } else {
        writeHeader(new RequestHeader(clientId, getNextRequestId(),
                RequestCommand.SEND_DATA, (byte) 0));
        output.write(bytes);
        writeEOF();
        RequestHeader header = handleHeader();
        if (header == null || header.getRequestCommand() != RequestCommand.ACK) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to send message");
        }
    }
}
```

### writeHeader and writeEOF:

```
private void writeHeader(RequestHeader header) throws IOException {
    output.write(header.toBytes());
}

private void writeEOF() throws IOException {
    output.write(EOF);
}
```

Comment: The fact that you've got `writeEOF` in a loop isn't ideal... but then, we don't know what that method, or `writeHeader`, does...

Comment: writeEOF is called inside and outside the loop. If that writes the end of file it probably shouldn't be inside the loop. All the +1 and -1 is odd as well. You should just do that once e.g. ADJUSTED_BUFFER SIZE = BUFFER_SIZE -1;

Comment: I would remove all the uses of `Array.copyOfRange` This just makes your code slower and more complicated. Note `write(byte[])` calls `write(byte[], offset, length)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I always appreciate getting tips on better coding style.
@JonSkeet I just added the writeHeader and writeEOF methods.

Comment: Well without knowing what EOF is, or what `header.toBytes()` does, or what the expected protocol is, that's still not really enough information...

Comment: @JonSkeet I just pasted all my code except for the main method on pastebin. [link](http://pastebin.com/AcQpM0TB)

Comment: A short but complete example would have been preferable, to be honest. There's a lot of extraneous information there. Additionally, we have no idea what you're seeing on the server side. There's a *lot* of diagnostic work you could be doing, logging each header you're receiving and the data associated with it. I strongly suspect that if you just dig in a bit further in terms of what's being sent and received, you'll find the problem.